Angular: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstCreatePass') after adding Drag and Drop
In my Angular task manager app, when I added drag and drop system, I got this error

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstCreatePass') task-view.component.ts:29      at providersResolver (core.mjs:27506:15)     at definition.providersResolver (core.mjs:27767:24)     at initializeDirectives (core.mjs:11806:17)     at resolveDirectives (core.mjs:11780:13)     at elementStartFirstCreatePass (core.mjs:22955:5)     at Module.ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:22991:9)     at TaskViewComponent_div_14_Template (task-view.component.html:45:13)     at executeTemplate (core.mjs:11268:9)     at renderView (core.mjs:12470:13)     at createAndRenderEmbeddedLView (core.mjs:12540:9)

Here is my task-view.component.html template:
<div class="centered-content">

    <div class="task-manager-container">

        <div class="side-bar has-background-white">
            <h1 class="title has-text-primary">Boards</h1>

            <div class="list-menu">
                <a class="list-menu-item" *ngFor="let list of lists" [routerLink]="['/lists', list?._id]" routerLinkActive="is-active">
                    <p>{{ list?.title }}</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <button class="button is-primary has-text-white" routerLink="/new-list">+ New board</button>
        </div>

        <div class="tasks-list-container has-background-light" [ngClass]="{ 'empty': !isListSelected() || tasks.length === 0}">

            <div class="top-bar" [ngClass]="{ 'empty-board': tasks.length === 0}">
                <h1 class="title has-text-primary" *ngIf="isListSelected() && tasks.length > 0">Tasks</h1>

                <div *ngIf="isListSelected()" class="dropdown is-hoverable is-right">
                    <div class="dropdown-trigger">
                      <button id="drop-btn" class="button has-text-black has-background-light" aria-haspopup="true">
                        <span class="icon is-small">
                          <i class="fas fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu4" role="menu">
                      <div class="dropdown-content" style="border: 2px solid lightgrey;">
                        <div class="dropdown-item">
                            <a [routerLink]="['/edit-list', selectedListId]" class="dropdown-item has-text-black">Edit</a>
                            <a (click)="onDeleteListClick();" class="dropdown-item has-text-danger">Delete</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            
            <h3 *ngIf="isListSelected() && tasks.length === 0">No tasks here</h3>


            <div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" *ngIf="tasks && tasks.length > 0" class="tasks" [ngClass]=" { 'scrollable': tasks.length >= 5}">

                <!-- Task Elements  -->
                <div class="task" ngIf="tasks && tasks.length > 0" *ngFor="let task of tasks" (click)="onTaskClick(task)" [ngClass]="{ completed: task.completed }">
                    <div class="task-text" cdkDrag>
                        <p>{{ task.title }}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="task-buttons">
                        <button class="button is-info" [routerLink]="['/lists', selectedListId, 'edit-task', task._id]">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
                            </div>
                        </button>

                        <button class="button is-danger" (click)="onDeleteTaskClick(task._id);" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <button class="circle-add-button button is-primary" *ngIf="isListSelected()" routerLink="./new-task">
                <img src="../../../assets/plus-icon.svg">
            </button>

            <div class="empty-state" *ngIf="!isListSelected()">
                <h3>Select a board</h3>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <button id="logout" class="button is-outlined" (click)="onLogoutButtonClick();">Logout</button>

</div>

task-view.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from '../../task.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Task } from '../../models/task.model';
import { List } from '../../models/list.model';
import { CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-view',
  templateUrl: './task-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-view.component.scss'],
})

export class TaskViewComponent implements OnInit{

  lists: List[] = [];
  tasks: Task[] = [];
  selectedListId?: string | null;

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private authService: AuthService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {

        if (params['listId']) {
          this.selectedListId = params['listId'];
          this.taskService.getTasks(params['listId']).subscribe((tasks: Task[] | unknown) => {
            if (Array.isArray(tasks)) {
              if (this.tasks === null){
                console.log('tasks are null');
              }
              else{
                this.tasks = tasks;
                console.log(this.tasks);
              }
              
            }
          });
        }
        else {
          this.selectedListId = null;
        }
        
      }
    )

    this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists: List[] | unknown) => {
      if (Array.isArray(lists)){
        this.lists = lists;
      }
    });
  }

  isListSelected(): boolean {
    return !!this.selectedListId;
  }

  onTaskClick(task: Task) {
    // We want to set the task to be completed
    this.taskService.completed(task).subscribe(() => {
      task.completed = !task.completed;
    });
  }

  onDeleteListClick() {
    if (this.selectedListId) { // Check if selectedListId is not null
      this.taskService.deleteList(this.selectedListId).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/lists']);
        console.log(res);
      });
    }
  }

  onDeleteTaskClick(id: string) {
    if (this.selectedListId) { // Check if selectedListId is not null
      this.taskService.deleteTask(this.selectedListId, id).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.tasks = this.tasks.filter(val => val._id !== id);
        console.log(res);
      });
    }
  }

  onLogoutButtonClick(){
    this.authService.logout();
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.tasks, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }

}

app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TaskViewComponent } from './pages/task-view/task-view.component';
import { NewListComponent } from './pages/new-list/new-list.component';
import { NewTaskComponent } from './pages/new-task/new-task.component';
import { LoginPageComponent } from './pages/login-page/login-page.component';
import { WebReqInterceptor } from './web-req.interceptor';
import { SignupPageComponent } from './pages/signup-page/signup-page.component';
import { EditListComponent } from './pages/edit-list/edit-list.component';
import { EditTaskComponent } from './pages/edit-task/edit-task.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TaskViewComponent,
    NewListComponent,
    NewTaskComponent,
    LoginPageComponent,
    SignupPageComponent,
    EditListComponent,
    EditTaskComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    DragDropModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: WebReqInterceptor, multi: true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

I've tried to turn on "preserveSymlinks" option in angular.json. It doesn't help. What's the problem?
